# How to name a route in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some routes looking like this :

```
match 'hotels/:action(/:id)', :controller => 'hotel', :action => /[a-z]+/i, :id => /[0-9]+/i
```

And i want to use something like **hotels_dislike_path** somewhere in my code which refers to /hotels/dislike

How can i do that?

Comment: you want to name the routes according to the regexp? Don't think it's possible, because if so, it would cerate an infinity of routes. If the `as` answers yor need, I'd undelete my answer

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From the [routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes):

> ### 3.6 Naming Routes
>
> You can specify a name for any route using the :as option.
>
> ```
> match 'exit' => 'sessions#destroy', :as => :logout
> ```

So, in your case, that would be:

```
match 'hotels/:action(/:id)', :controller => 'hotel', :action => /[a-z]+/i, :id => /[0-9]+/i
match 'hotels/dislike(/:id)', :controller => 'hotel', :id => /[0-9]+/i, :as => :hotels_dislike
match 'hotels/like(/:id)', :controller => 'hotel', :id => /[0-9]+/i, :as => :hotels_like
```

I don't think there's a way to do this dynamically (so you have to define one route for each action, basically). However, you can just define a couple of routes (like above) for the most used actions, and just use `hotels_path :action => :really_like` for more uncommon actions.

Answer (score 20):

A lot has changed in the world of Rails since 2011 - this is how you would accomplish the same goal in Rails 4.

```
resources :hotels do
  member do
    post 'dislike'
    post 'like'
  end
end
```

The resulting routes:

```
   dislike_hotel POST     /hotels/:id/dislike(.:format)   hotels#dislike
      like_hotel POST     /hotels/:id/like(.:format)      hotels#like
          hotels GET      /hotels(.:format)               hotels#index
                 POST     /hotels(.:format)               hotels#create
       new_hotel GET      /hotels/new(.:format)           hotels#new
      edit_hotel GET      /hotels/:id/edit(.:format)      hotels#edit
           hotel GET      /hotels/:id(.:format)           hotels#show
                 PATCH    /hotels/:id(.:format)           hotels#update
                 PUT      /hotels/:id(.:format)           hotels#update
                 DELETE   /hotels/:id(.:format)           hotels#destro
```

Notice thats rails prefixes instead of postfixes the action - `dislike_hotel_path` not `hotels_dislike`.

Comment: I added an updated answer since this question has a very high search rank.