# Using a named route to generate a simple link using my match route format

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, link-to

Here are the routes I've written:

```
Foo::Application.routes.draw do
  get "home/index"

  match "/ads/:category_name" => "ads#by_category"
  match "/ads/:category_name/:id" => "ads#show"

  resources :ads

  root :to => 'home#index'
end
```

In one of my shared views, I wrote a sidebar element that displays all categories:

```
<div id="category-sidebar">
  <h2>Categorias</h2>
  <% Category.order('name').each do |category| %>
    <%= link_to category.name %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

This generates:

```
<div id="category-sidebar">
  <h2>Categorias</h2>
    <a href="/ads/Aeronautica">Aeronautica</a>
    <a href="/ads/Aeronautica">Agropecuaria y Campo</a>
    <a href="/ads/Aeronautica">Alimentos y Bebidas</a>
    <a href="/ads/Aeronautica">Animales y Mascotas</a>
    <a href="/ads/Aeronautica">Arte y Antiguedades</a>
</div>
```

---

I'd like to generate an `href` like:

```
/ads/Aeronautica
/ads/Alimentos%20y%20Bebidas
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use bundle exec rake routes to find the named route for your "/ads/:category_name/:id" path. Let's say that this route is called 'categories'. You can then do (note the '_path' bit):

```
Category.order('name').each do |category|
  link_to category.name, categories_path(:id => category.id)
end
```

Comment: Great tip, thank you! How can I give the path a name in `routes.rb`?

Comment: If you're not happy with the names rails generates by default, you can explicitly name a route like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913682/how-to-name-a-route-in-rails